# Filling missing value with mean for all columns in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to fill missing values in my pyspark 3.0.1 data frame using mean. I'm looking for pandas like `fillna` function. For example

```
df=df.fillna(df.mean())
```

But so far I have found, in pyspark, is filling missing value using mean for a single column, not for whole dataset.

Can you suggest me how do I implement pandas like `fillna` in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to get the mean for all columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import numpy as np

avg = np.mean([i for i in df.select([F.mean(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0] if i is not None])

df2 = df.fillna(avg)
```